# Places/Landmarks to see in West Lafayette, Indiana

Tags: usa, business-travel

I will be visiting Purdue university to give a talk in a week. Unfortunately the only free hours I will have are the evening of the 10th of March and that of the 11th of March. I checked Tripadvisor for "tourism" worthy spots in the area but was disappointed. It would seem that Purdue University itself seems to be worth "looking" at.

What would a business traveler do for two evenings of tourism in West Lafayette, Indiana. I will be staying close to Purdue University.

Options I am looking for are: Old/Important landmarks, Landmark areas at Purdue, good food (Mexican, Italian, fusion, $-$$)? Or is it just Purdue that will have to be my "entertainment"? `:)`

Comment: My alma mater. :)  Unfortunately there is not much in a matter of entertainment or landmarks in Lafayette or West Lafayette.  Purdue campus is nice but it is not very big.

Comment: @Karlson So does the campus have decent places to grab dinner, say after 7pm? Is it a bustling campus? Does it have any landmarks? You have NOT seen my tiny campus! 7000 students strong `;)`

Comment: Purdue is close to 30k

Comment: The campus has changed a lot since I was there last.  But it's basically a memorial mall, which has some of the if not original buildings from its founding but close, a couple of fountains, the main one in engineering mall has significance to students.  On top of this I was a student there so for me La Bamba Burito was a good dinner. :)

Comment: We do expect people to do some preliminary research and to narrow down your interests as much as possible; you're within two hours of Chicago, for example, which would offer a bit of everything. http://www.homeofpurdue.com/ suggests agritourism, historical sites, garden viewings, and antiquing among other attractions.

Comment: @choster Yes, I am aware of that from my involvement in other SE sites. The key point here is I perhaps have a total of 10 hours spread between 2 evenings and what I could accomplish as far as tourism goes for these hours! `:)`